# How to write acceptance tests

Tags: .net, testing, acceptance-testing

How would you go about introducing acceptance tests into a team using the .NET framework?  What tools are available for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to take a look at FitNesse, which is meant to be a way for Acceptance tests to look like a wiki document (so that they can be read and written by QA or project managers)

http://fitnesse.org/

Here's a good intro

http://ablog.apress.com/?p=735

Answer (score 1):

See this post, I think its a good idea to first understand what an acceptance test is. Is your question not how to introduce Unit testing, which is the sister of Acceptance Tests. 
For .Framework they should use NMock and NUnit.

Also worth while checking BDD

[How detailed should a customer acceptance test be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832403/how-detailed-should-a-customer-acceptance-test-be)